# Uncaught TypeError: selector is undefined

Tags: jquery

What is wrong with this part of jQuery code?

```
$(this).parents('.list-footer').prev().find('div').find(`div:not:contains('${this.value.trim()}')`).css('display', 'none');
```

It gives this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: selector is undefined
    jQuery 7
    onkeyup http://localhost:3000/account:1
jquery-3.3.1.js:1927:15
    jQuery 7
    onkeyup http://localhost:3000/account:1
```

Answer (score 1):

I just found out jQuery `:not()` selector must be used with parentheses.

```
div:not(:contains('${this.value.trim()}')
```